# How to create middlewares to restrict access to certain pages in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have the following website structure:

- /index.vue - Login Page
- /admin/* - Only users with role 'employee' or 'owner' can access if logged in
- /* - Only users with role 'customer' can access if logged in

I have two layouts

- admin-dashboard applied to all /admin/* routes
- customer-dashboard applied to all /* routes

Now I am trying to create middlewares to restrict access to the routes based on the role of the user. How do I approach this problem?

Comment: For each route add propriety like: requireAdminRole: true and use interceptors to check user role before enter on this route

Comment: @Radeanu Can you point me to any code example or resources?

Comment: https://dev.to/husteadrobert/how-to-use-global-navigation-guards-with-nuxt-middleware-and-why-you-absolutely-should-not-7bl